# How can I make the following code into a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, formatting

Also, how do I make it so all of the square brackets and "s are all gone so it looks like a connect 4 board?

```
Row7 = [" ","A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]  
Row6 = ["1","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]  
Row5 = ["2","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]  
Row4 = ["3","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]  
Row3 = ["4","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]  
Row2 = ["5","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]  
Row1 = ["6","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]

board = [[Row7], [Row6], [Row5], [Row4], [Row3], [Row2], [Row1]]

print (board)
```

So, if possible, I would like it to look something like this:

A B C D E F G

1 - - - - - - -

2 - - - - - - -

3 - - - - - - -

4 - - - - - - -

5 - - - - - - -

6 - - - - - - -

It needs to be a 2D array too!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried so far. You cannot expect someone to code for you. That is the way you learn brother.

Comment: I tried using numpy to extend the line, but I couldn't seem to get that to work

Comment: Exactly. We need to know what you tried. Add that code snippet to your description.

Comment: My problem is sorted now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare the board as a 2d array (list of lists)

```
board = [[" ","A","B","C","D","E","F","G"],
         ["1","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"],  
         ["2","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"],  
         ["3","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"],  
         ["4","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"],  
         ["5","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"],  
         ["6","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]]
#or if you need the rows
# Row7 is an list... so board will be a list of lists (2d array) 
# board = [Row7, Row6, Row5, Row4, Row3, Row2, Row1]

def printB( board ) :
   for row in board: 
      print( " ".join(row) )


printB( board )


>  A B C D E F G
 1 - - - - - - -
 2 - - - - - - -
 3 - - - - - - -
 4 - - - - - - -
 5 - - - - - - -
 6 - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!